# Birt Report Viewer - Tomcat 's killed without error?

Tags: java, tomcat, birt

I build birt.war on tomcat (Ubuntu , OpenJDK), when i run birt viewer, tomcat 's killed without any error. Frown | :( I build the same on my windows pc, it 's fine. Smile | :) ...please help me to solve this, tks so much !!!

Comment: which version are you using ? make sure that you follow the instructions which mentioned in the below link http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-install-tomcat-in-ubuntu/

Comment: i run tomcat on remote server (ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: I fixed this error with tomcat 6. Changing to tomcat 6, if someone get the same error. tks